# ReloadData from another class cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to update tableview from the button pressed in another tableviewcell.
Here is code of my VC with table view:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var teamTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordsTable: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        wordsForTheRound.removeLast()
        print(results)
        
        teamTable.delegate = self
        teamTable.dataSource = self
        wordsTable.delegate = self
        wordsTable.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.teamTable {return results.count}
        if tableView == self.wordsTable {return results[0].words.count}
        return 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == self.teamTable {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ResultsTeamsCell") as? ResultsTeamsCell {
                cell.updateCell(result: results[indexPath.row])
                return cell
            }
        }
        if tableView == self.wordsTable {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ResultsWordsCell") as? ResultsWordsCell {
                cell.updateCell(wordIncmoing: results[0].words[indexPath.row], tf: results[0].wordIsCorrect[indexPath.row])
                return cell
            }
        }
            return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func reloadTables(_ sender: Any) {
        teamTable.reloadData()
        wordsTable.reloadData()
    }
    
    


}
```

and the code of my tableviewcell where I need the **teamTable** to reload whilte i tap on buttons **TFBtnPressed**

```
import UIKit

class ResultsWordsCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var word: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TFBtn: UIButton!
    
    func updateCell(wordIncmoing: String, tf: Bool) {
        word.text = wordIncmoing
        TFBtn.setTitle("\(tf)", for: .normal)
    }
    @IBAction func TFBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if TFBtn.title(for: .normal) == "false" {
            TFBtn.setTitle("true", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score += 1
           
            print(results)
        } else {
            TFBtn.setTitle("false", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score -= 1
           
            print(results)
        }
    }
    
    func changeWordStatus(word: String) {
        for i in 0...results[0].words.count - 1 {
            if word == results[0].words[i] {
                results[0].wordIsCorrect[i] = !results[0].wordIsCorrect[i]
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I read a lot of articles and it is probably that it should set up a tableview delegate, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: You need to access the UITableView from your cell, but as it is you have no link in between. Add a field for this in your cell and fill it from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @jean-baptiste-yunès I am using two different table views. I need to upodate TableView1 from TableViewCell2

Comment: Almost the same answer, objects must know each other to communicate.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I am new to swift, could you please provide more info with code, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a protocol to have communication between your view controller and table view cell.

Create a new protocol inside of your "ResultsWordsCell";

```
import UIKit
            
protocol ResultsWordsCellDelegate {
    func didTapRefreshButton()
}
            
class ResultsWordsCell: UITableViewCell {
    .....
    var resultsWordsCellDelegate: ResultsWordsCellDelegate?
    .....
    @IBAction func TFBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        .....
        resultsWordsCellDelegate?.didTapRefreshButton()
        .....
    }
```

On ResultsVC' s cellForRowAt func;

add -> `cell.resultsWordsCellDelegate = self`

Now, create a new extension on ResultsVC;

```
class ResultsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
.....
.....
}

extension ResultsVC: ResultsWordsCellDelegate {
    func didTapRefreshButton {
        self.wordsTable.reloadData()
        self.teamTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works for me. Could you share any article to read about how this works under the hood?

Comment: @drebin96 That is exactly what I told you in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use clouser.
first create typealise for callBack like this:

```
typealias CallBack = () -> Void
```

and define clouser inside tableViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var word: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TFBtn: UIButton!

public var callBack: CallBack?
```

and call variable inside TFBtnPressed:

```
@IBAction func TFBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if TFBtn.title(for: .normal) == "false" {
            TFBtn.setTitle("true", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score += 1
           
            print(results)
        } else {
            TFBtn.setTitle("false", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score -= 1
           
            print(results)
        }
        
        // set callBack
        callBack?()
    }
```

and inside dequeue Cell change this:

```
   cell.updateCell(wordIncmoing: results[0].words[indexPath.row], tf: results[0].wordIsCorrect[indexPath.row])
        
        cell.callBack = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            
// reload table here
            self.wordsTable.reloadData()
            self.teamTable.reloadData()
            
        }
```

all code ResultWordsCell:

```
typealias CallBack = () -> Void

class ResultsWordsCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var word: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var TFBtn: UIButton!
    public var callBack: CallBack?
    
    func updateCell(wordIncmoing: String, tf: Bool) {
        word.text = wordIncmoing
        TFBtn.setTitle("\(tf)", for: .normal)
    }
    @IBAction func TFBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if TFBtn.title(for: .normal) == "false" {
            TFBtn.setTitle("true", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score += 1
           
            print(results)
        } else {
            TFBtn.setTitle("false", for: .normal)
            changeWordStatus(word: word.text!)
            results[0].score -= 1
           
            print(results)
        }
        
        // set callBack
        callBack?()
    }
    
    
    
    func changeWordStatus(word: String) {
        for i in 0...results[0].words.count - 1 {
            if word == results[0].words[i] {
                results[0].wordIsCorrect[i] = !results[0].wordIsCorrect[i]
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: How to set callBack?, it shows me an error that "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"? And at my VC it writes that Value of type 'ResultsWordsCell' has no member 'callBack'

Comment: You must define a variable of type CallBack. me update my answer and send all code inside ResultsWordsCell file. try again. Tell me if you still have problems